# How to change a string into a variable

Tags: string, variables, replace

I want to write out some data into a file. I saved the filename as a `variable`. I wan to use `%` mode to substitude the `variable` to the text, but it gives an error:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
writeafile = open('N:\myfile\%s.txt' , "a") % (variable)
```

Comment: Please tag the question with the computer language you're using, that way, people who have experience of that language can see that the question may be something they'd like to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about Python here, you should move `variable` next to the
`'N:\\myfile\\%s.txt'` string for correct syntax, like so:
`writeafile = open("N:\\myfile\\%s.txt" % variable, "a")`

However, using this style of formatting is not recommended by Pydocs:

> The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer formatted string literals, the str.format() interface, or template strings may help avoid these errors. Each of these alternatives provides their own trade-offs and benefits of simplicity, flexibility, and/or extensibility.
>   [Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

So, I'd suggest using f-strings, which have been available in Python since 3.6. The double `\\` is intentional here, otherwise Python will treat it as an escape character and you'll get undesired results.
`writeafile = open(f"N:\\myfile\\{variable}.txt", "a")`

Alternatively, you could also use `str.format()`:
`writeafile = open("N:\\myfile\\{name}.txt".format(name=variable), "a")`

Comment: @Andrew Morton I've tested the examples quickly and it seemed to work, but you're right, it would probably be better if all backslashes were properly escaped.